# Cant Access FTP account using proftpd on Azure

Tags: server, client, nat, azure, proftpd

i created VM on cloud with ubuntu 22.04 and installed Proftpd server .
this Server is behind Firewall NSV270 .

i can aces sftp Account using external IP , but i cant acess FTP using any ftp client , using passive or active modes its give me this error

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Plain FTP is insecure. Please switch to FTP over TLS.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PORT 172,16,100,3,253,5
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

i dont know what is the issue exactly .

Thanks